Can I present an article at a conference, if it has previously been put on arxiv and sent to a journal?
I have written a research article in the field of mathematics. This article has been put by me at https://arxiv.org/, which means now it is accessible by anyone, and also this article has been communicated to an SCIE journal (Science Citation Index Expanded journal). I want to present this article at an international conference. Will there be any ethical issues or conflicts, if I present it at a conference?

Does the conference call for papers ask for original works?  Will there be a conference proceedings volume published, and do papers in the conference proceedings volume have to be original works?  Does the journal expect exclusive publishing rights?  There are situations where it would be completely unacceptable to submit this to a conference, and others where it's normal to have conference presentations based on already published papers.

Question: what does "communicated to a journal" mean? I am not familiar with that

@Pronte Submitted for possible publication

Ok I put in my answer, short story is ask the editor because it's a coin flip

This is totally fine, don't worry about it.
In mathematics, many journals have very long reviewing cycles. It can take a few years before a submitted journal is accepted or rejected. Thus, it is common practice for mathematicians to "informally publish" papers on the arXiv.
For most purposes, in mathematics, preprints are almost as good as published papers. People cite them, present them (even at venues like the ICM!), and even use them for job applications. Many of the biggest recent advances in mathematics remain unpublished (e.g., Scholze and Clausen's condensed mathematics), even though they have drawn global attention.
In fact, giving a talk about it will generally decrease the chance that someone else scoops it, as your work will be known to at least a group of people and they will be aware that the ideas are yours.
As for ethical concerns and review conflicts, there are none. Double-blind reviewing is not really a thing in mathematics (or really, not possible at all). In principle, there are journals that are double blind, but de facto they are really just single-blind in all practicality (no reference anonymization and no reviewer opt-out for seen work, in general, as that could make it nearly impossible to find reviewers in some cases). So don't worry.

Indeed I have presented my work before even making it to the posting-a-finished-manuscript-online stage. (The time I'm working on the paper is the time I'm most excited about the topic!) I wouldn't specifically aim for this, and I've had the final version differ from what I presented in the past, but it hasn't been a big deal in the end.

@GregMartin Indeed, and some mathematicians prefer their own website over arXiv anyways.

You absolutely need to refer to the journal's guidelines!
It may change from journal to journal, e.g., in computer science it would typically not be allowed, but CS tents to give conferences a lot more relevance compared to other fields
If you're in doubt, why not asking the journal editor?

Any journal that would object can as well declare themselves closed for business.

That's simply wrong. Would, for example be ok to communicate the paper to another journal simultaneously? Of course not. - in some fields (like computer science) conference proceedings are considered on the same level as journals, so that could be considered a double submission

Presenting an article at a conference is not the same as submitting it to the proceedings of a conference.

Nope, the main concern would be your paper is rejected, and then before you can get it accepted, someone "scoops" your message without plagiarizing, thus devaluing your original contribution. If you're not worried about that, then I see no issues.
Depending on the field, it might be seen as bad taste to only present work that is currently under peer review (I would hope that you at least get past desk reject). But, if you can also point to previous work that is formally published (with non-arxiv doi), then that will give you credibility.

None of this is of concern in the field of mathematics, as far as I'm concerned.

I should add I'm an engineer and not a mathematician
